# Order $3$ canonical subgroup of elliptic curve. (The valuation of Hasse invariant)

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, elliptic-curves

In F. Calegari's [lecture notes](https://www.math.arizona.edu/%7Eswc/aws/2013/2013CalegariLectureNotes.pdf), Exercise.3.0.4 is: Show the $v_{3}(a_{2})<\frac{3}{4}$ being the sufficient condition for an elliptic curve having canonical order $3$ subgroup, where $v_{3}$ denotes a valuation of $\mathcal{O}_{K}$ s.t. $v_{3}(3)=1.$
Here the elliptic curve is defined over the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_{K}$ with finite extension $K/\Bbb{Q}_{3}$ given by the minimal Weierstrass equation: $$y^{2}+a_{1}xy+a_{3}y=x^{3}+a_{2}x^{2}+a_{4}x+a_{6}.$$

I failed in solving this exercise.

The present question consists of the above part (any hints will be very welcomed) and the following:

Nevertheless, I found something weird while trying to solve this problem and I would like to ask why the following has happened (or say, what's wrong?):
Assume now we dealing with an elliptic curve given by $F$ over $K/\Bbb{Q}_{3},$
with
$$F(x,y,x_{2})=y^{2}x_{2}-x^{3}-Axx_{2}^{2}-Bx_{2}^{3}=0.$$
This enables us to apply Excercise.3.9 (Silverman. The arith. of ell. curve.) which claims that $P+P+P=O$ (the group structure of elliptic curve) iff the determinant of the Hessian (with $x_{0}:=x,$ $x_{1}:=y$)
$$\text{det}\bigg(\frac{\partial^{2}F}{\partial x_{i}x_{j}}\bigg)_{0\leq i,j\leq 2}$$ equals $0.$
Require the determinant of Hessian vanishing at $P=(x,y,x_{2})$ and $P$ belonging to the curve given by $F.$
After some routine calculations,
the following equation is deduced after $x_{2}=1$ is assumed:
$$x^{4}+\frac{3}{2}Ax^{2}+\frac{5}{2}Bx-A^{3}/6=0.$$
Since $``2(v_{3}(A)+1)<v_{3}(A^{2})-1$ never happening $"$ indicates $4$ solutions of this equation never has different valuations, we seem to obtain the claim that order $3$ canonical subgroup does not exist in the elliptic curve given by $F,$ which looks wired. (See p.27 of F. Calegari's lecture for a similar argument).

Comment: Sorry for such a long verbose description. Please let me know if I made any mistakes.